# Optimal way to write a class in fortran 2018 (Code review)

Tags: arrays, class, fortran, fortran2018

I tried to write a code in modern fortran (2018?) and one of my goals is to be able to convert subroutines like this one (old fortran 77) to the most recent fortran (2018?)

```
    subroutine nobin(e,j,f)
         common/binin/bini(40),nbn
         er=e
         do 100 i=j,40
         er=er-bini(i)
         if(er.le.0.0) go to 200
         100 continue
         f1=er/bini(40)
         f=41.+f1-float(j)
         if(j.gt.40) f=f1
         go to 300
     200 f=float(i-j)+er/bini(i)+1.0
     300 continue
         return
         end
```

So far, I was able to write something like this (see below) but I was successful only for scalar variables. I am kind of stuck when I have to use arrays. In particular I should allocate and then give some values to the array Bini (the common block in the old fortran subroutine). And then to use these array in the function (find_bin_nobin) defined in the class. Any suggestion is appreciated as well as any formal improvement to the code. Many Thanks!

```
   module precision
   implicit none
   public
   integer, parameter :: pr = selected_real_kind(12,300)
   integer, parameter :: ir = 4
   end module precision

   module constants
   use precision
   implicit none
   public
   real   ( kind = pr ), parameter :: zero  = 0.0_pr
   real   ( kind = pr ), parameter :: one   = 1.0_pr
   real   ( kind = pr ), parameter :: four  = 4.0_pr
   real   ( kind = pr ), parameter :: pi = four * atan(one)
   end module constants

   module class_Dntrnpr

   use precision
   use constants, only : zero, one
   implicit none
   type Find_bin
   real   ( kind = pr ) :: e
   integer( kind = ir ) :: j
   real   ( kind = pr ), allocatable, dimension(:) :: bin

    contains

   procedure :: f => find_bin_nobin
   end type Find_bin

   contains

   function find_bin_nobin(x, n) result(f)
    class(Find_bin), intent(inout) :: x
    integer( kind = ir ), intent(in) :: n
    real   ( kind = pr ) :: f, f1, er
    integer( kind = ir ) :: i, k
    allocate(x%bin(n))
    er = x%e
    i  = x%j
    k  = i
    er = er - x%bin(i)
    do while ( er <= zero )
     er = er - x%bin(i)
     i = i + 1
    enddo
    f1 = er / x%bin(n)
    f  = ( n + 1 ) + f1 - dble(k) 
    if ( k > n ) then
     f = f1; return
    else
     f = dble(i-k) + er / x%bin(i) + one
    endif
    return
    end function find_bin_nobin

   end module class_Dntrnpr

   program test

   use class_Dntrnpr
   implicit none

   integer( kind = ir ) :: nbmax,i
   real   ( kind = pr ), allocatable, dimension(:) :: bini

   type(Find_bin) :: en
   !  type(Find_bin), allocatable, dimension(:) :: bin

   en%e = 2.0
   en%j = 1
   nbmax = 40

   allocate(bini(nbmax))
   bini = 1.0

   end program test
```

Comment: While it is a nice question, it seems to fit more into CodeReview.

Comment: @mcocdawc, Thanks for the suggestion. I changed the title of the post including Code review. I hope I did it right. This is my first question/post.

Comment: I believe @mcocdawc is referring to the site like Stack Overflow which is dedicated specifically to reviewing working code: that's [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour). I don't know that it is on topic there, but it's certainly worth considering.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like it might be more suited to [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I'm going to throw in my six cents anyway. Apologies in advance if I come off rude below; it's not my intent, I'm just trying to make suggestions as I see them, and to avoid cluttering advice with niceties.

### module precision

```
   module precision
   implicit none
   public
   integer, parameter :: pr = selected_real_kind(12,300)
   integer, parameter :: ir = 4
   end module precision
```

- If you're using free-form Fortran (and you really should be), you should indent for readability.
- `selected_real_kind(15,307)` is [more standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22362211/confusing-double-precision-real-in-fortran) than `(12,300)` for double precision. Maybe consider instead using `real64` from `iso_fortran_env`.
- `selected_int_kind(9)` is more portable than `4`.

So I would write this as:

```
module precision
  implicit none
  public
  integer, parameter :: pr = selected_real_kind(15,307)
  integer, parameter :: ir = selected_int_kind(9)
end module precision
```

### module constants

```
   module constants
   use precision
   implicit none
   public
   real   ( kind = pr ), parameter :: zero  = 0.0_pr
   real   ( kind = pr ), parameter :: one   = 1.0_pr
   real   ( kind = pr ), parameter :: four  = 4.0_pr
   real   ( kind = pr ), parameter :: pi = four * atan(one)
   end module constants
```

- Indentation again.
- Parameters like `zero = 0.0_pr` are generally bad practice. With a modern compiler they won't give you any speedup, and they reduce readability. Just use the actual numbers.
- I prefer `real(pr)` over `real (kind = pr)`. It conveys the same information, and is more concise.

So I would write this as:

```
module constants
  use precision
  implicit none
  public
  real(pr), parameter :: pi = 4.0_pr * atan(1.0_pr)
end module constants
```

### Class definition

```
   module class_Dntrnpr

   use precision
   use constants, only : zero, one
   implicit none
   type Find_bin
   real   ( kind = pr ) :: e
   integer( kind = ir ) :: j
   real   ( kind = pr ), allocatable, dimension(:) :: bin

    contains

   procedure :: f => find_bin_nobin
   end type Find_bin

   contains
```

- Indentation again.
- If all a module does is define a class, it should be named after that class.
- It's [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101958/code-formatting-is-lining-up-similar-lines-ok) to align multiple lines using extra spaces (e.g. your declaration of `e` and `j`).
- Consider renaming `Find_bin` to something more descriptive. Is this class a "find bin"?
- Does `bin` represent a single bin, or should it be `bins`?
- For consistency, `f => find_bin_nobin` should really be `nobin => nobin_Find_bin`.
- The function `find_bin_nobin` does two different things: intilalise `bin` and calculate `f`. Ideally, OOP procedures should be separated into `subroutine`s which modify their arguments and `function`s which do not modify their arguments. In this case, initialising `bin` can be done in a constructor.

So I would write this as:

```
module class_Find_bin
  use precision
  implicit none
  
  type Find_bin
    real(pr) :: e
    integer(ir) :: j
    real(pr), allocatable, dimension(:) :: bin
  contains
    procedure :: nobin => nobin_Find_bin
  end type Find_bin
  
  ! Constructor for type Find_bin.
  interface Find_bin
    module procedure new_Find_bin
  end interface
contains
```

### Class procedure(s)

```
   contains
   
   function find_bin_nobin(x, n) result(f)
    class(Find_bin), intent(inout) :: x
    integer( kind = ir ), intent(in) :: n
    real   ( kind = pr ) :: f, f1, er
    integer( kind = ir ) :: i, k
    allocate(x%bin(n))
    er = x%e
    i  = x%j
    k  = i
    er = er - x%bin(i)
    do while ( er <= zero )
     er = er - x%bin(i)
     i = i + 1
    enddo
    f1 = er / x%bin(n)
    f  = ( n + 1 ) + f1 - dble(k) 
    if ( k > n ) then
     f = f1; return
    else
     f = dble(i-k) + er / x%bin(i) + one
    endif
    return
    end function find_bin_nobin

   end module class_Dntrnpr
```

- Indentation again. Alignment of multiple lines again.
- Consider adding blank lines between sections of the code which do different things.
- As above, consider separating `find_bin_nobin` into a constructor and a function to calculate `f`.
- You never set `x%bin`. You allocate it with `allocate(x%bin(n))`, but then start reading from it without setting its values first.
- Your version of the loop across `i` is different to the old version.
- The variable `k` is unnecessary and adds confusion.
- `dble(foo)` should be `real(foo, pr)`.
- Avoid using `;` for two lines in one.
- In the old code, the `if(j.gt.40)` doesn't have an `else`. The line `200 f=float(i-j)+er/bini(i)+1.0` is always skipped by the line `go to 300`.
- You don't need `return` at the end of a procedure. That happens automatically.

So I would write this as:

```
contains
  function new_Find_bin(e, j, n) result(this)
    real(pr), intent(in) :: e
    integer(ir), intent(in) :: j
    integer(ir), intent(in) :: n
    type(Find_bin) :: this
    
    this%e = e
    this%j = j
    allocate(this%bin(n))
    ! Initialise bin here.
  end function
  
  function nobin_Find_bin(this) result(f)
    class(Find_bin), intent(in) :: this
    real(pr) :: f
    
    real(pr) :: f1, er
    integer(ir) :: i, n
    
    er = this%e
    n = size(this%bin)
    
    do i=this%j,n
      er = er - this%bin(i)
      if (er<=0.0_pr) then
        f = real(i-this%j, pr) + er/this%bin(i) + 1.0_pr
        return
      endif
    enddo
    
    f1 = er / this%bin(n)
    f  = ( n + 1 ) + f1 - real(this%j, pr)
    
    if ( this%j > n ) then
      f = f1
    endif
  end function find_bin_nobin
end module class_Find_bin
```

### Main program

```
   program test

   use class_Dntrnpr
   implicit none

   integer( kind = ir ) :: nbmax,i
   real   ( kind = pr ), allocatable, dimension(:) :: bini

   type(Find_bin) :: en
   !  type(Find_bin), allocatable, dimension(:) :: bin

   en%e = 2.0
   en%j = 1
   nbmax = 40

   allocate(bini(nbmax))
   bini = 1.0

   end program test
```

With the modules changed as above, I would write this as:

```
program test
  use class_Find_bin
  implicit none
  
  type(Find_bin) :: bin
  real(pr) :: f
  
  bin = Find_bin(2.0_pr, 1, 40)
  f = bin%nobin()
end program
```

### A general comment:

- Your code contains no comments and your variable names are meaningless. Future readers of your code (probably including future you) will be much happier if they can read what your code does rather than having to work it out. Consider replacing e.g. `e` and `er` with `error` if that's what they represent.

Comment: this is super helpful, thanks a lot! These are exactly the comments (not rude at all) that I need. By using your improvements I was able to successfully compile the test code (just for other readers, I had to change minor things like "x" to "this" in some place and also to delete ":: Find_bin" after interface). I agree with you I should have given a better explanatory and more meaningful subroutine. Working towards this but, so far, with your help, I was able to get conceptually what I wanted. Thanks!